# Is closing an ApplicationContext always (after its use) a good idea?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am working on a Spring Batch application, whether I have categorised the spring xml configs into 4 files. The first 2 files comprises of spring batch database and core application beans definitions (namely `database.xml` and `context.xml`). The next 2 files are dynamic, in the sense that, they depend on which batch script to execute.

So executing a batch script comprises of loading `context.xml`, `database.xml` + 2 script related files.

For example, to execute *"batch script 1"*, I have to load `batch1.xml` and `tasklet1.xml` along with 2 core configs, to execute *"batch script 2"*, I have to load `batch2.xml` and `tasklet2.xml` along with 2 core configs so on..

Due to this scenario, I need to create a new `ApplicationContext` when a request to run a batch script comes. Right now, once I create and use my `ApplicationContext`, I am destroying them by calling `close()` method. My question is, is creating and destroying the `ApplicationContext` for each run a good idea (performance and memory wise)? or are there any good alternate approach?

**EDIT:** I am already using **hierarchical contexts**. That means, for the 2 core configs, I am creating an ApplicationContext and keeping it in memory (static variable). And for a new request, I am creating a new ApplicationContext with the core context as parent.

```
public void runBatch(String batchXmlLoc, String taskletXmlLoc) {
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[]{batchXmlLoc, taskletXmlLoc}, getParent());
    //... do the work...
   ((ClassPathXmlApplicationContext)context).close();
}

private static ApplicationContext parent;

private ApplicationContext getParent() {
   if(parent == null) {
        parent = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("database.xml", "context.xml");
   }
   return parent;
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason for not reusing the 2 setups?

Comment: @Ralph, for the 2 core configs, I am reusing the ApplicationContext. That means, I am creating a base context and using it as "parent" context, while I create for the dynamic files

Comment: but why do you not reuse the child contexts?

Comment: @Ralph I agree. I think i will refactor my code and reuse the context, loading all the files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you need to restart the context after use (which would indicate a coding error anyway), you could simply use hierarchical contexts.
Create a root context with your database and core definitions and then create two child contexts using the following constructor:

```
public ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(String[] configLocations,
                                  ApplicationContext parent)
```

The two child contexts won't see or intefere with each other.

If you need to restart the context, you should consider to refactor your setup. A spring context should not contain any stateful information like this. A possible solution might be to create a factory bean, that takes the run arguments and builds the necessary classes for the batch run.

Comment: Thank you @nfechner for your answer. Sorry, I forgot to mention that I am already doing this. Is there a more better approach?

Comment: Then why do you need to restart the different contexts? Do they keep state of some kind? Or different: What keeps you from creating all three contexts at startup?

Comment: Yes, I have "job inputs" stored in the batch xml. These inputs differ, in different contexts.

Comment: So, a possible way might be to refactor that out of the context. I updated my answer a bit to reflect that.

Comment: Ok, I agree with the fact that I need to make the context state free. What if I have 100+ batch scripts in my system. Is it good idea to load them all (eventually), by keeping the context open? will it not cause issue?

Comment: My favorite answer: That depends. :-) Mostly on the size of the scripts and the amount of RAM available on the prod system. I'd say: Try it.
You could also load the scripts only per run (and not create them as managed spring beans).

Comment: I am accepting this answer and drawing this conclusion - *It is better to create context at once and reuse them (for this refactor the code to make config stateless), instead of creating and closing them many times.*